# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

Stored procedure throws an error:

> error SQL (error 156) [SQLSTATE 4200] "Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'where'."

The stored procedure does successfully populate the table by using `INSERT` statement, but I keep getting this error when it runs.  I'm not sure how to fix the error.

Here is the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BuildTable]

AS

declare @QueryTxt as varchar(max)
declare @QueryName as varchar(50)
declare @ColumnVal as int
declare @CountVal as varchar(50)

declare @isFirst char(1)
declare @currentDT as varchar(20)
declare @savdate as datetime

BEGIN
set @isFirst = 'Y';             
set @currentDT = convert(varchar(20),current_timestamp,110);

declare c1 cursor for select queryname, querytext from subsqueries
open c1

 fetch next from c1 into @queryname, @querytxt
    while @@FETCH_STATUS  = 0   
    begin 
          --call stored proc
         exec InformixQuery @querytxt, @ColumnVal output

         set @CountVal = ltrim(str(@ColumnVal))
         if @isFirst = 'Y' 
          begin   
           exec ('insert into TblHistory (' + @queryname + ',transdate) values(' + @CountVal + ',' + '''' + @currentDT + '''' + ')')
            set @isFirst = 'N'
          end
         else
         begin
           exec ('update TblHistory set ' + @queryname + ' = ' + @CountVal + ' where transdate = ' + '''' + @currentDT + '''') 
         end
      fetch next from c1 into @queryname, @querytxt      
    end
close c1
deallocate c1
end
```

Comment: why do you have mysql tagged? this appears to be sql server

Comment: trying printing your exec update statement rather than execing it to confirm that it is what you think it is and with valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there are some variables missing. Barring that, the queryname fields looks like a varchar column. You need to surround the @countval with quotes.

```
exec ('update TblHistory set ' + @queryname + ' = ''' + @CountVal + ''' where transdate = ' + '''' + @currentDT + '''')
```

Comment: I think you may be right here.  Thank you for the reply.  I will test it and accept your answer if correct.